# How can I write $f^{-1}(R)$ in term of $Re f^{-1}$ and $Imf^{-1}$?

Tags: real-analysis

I am having confusion in the following:

If $f:\mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{C}$  is a complex valued function. For any rectangle $R=I_1\times I_2 \subset \mathbb{C}$ where $I_i \subset \mathbb{R}$. How can I write $f^{-1}(R)$ in term of ${\rm Re} f^{-1}$ and ${\rm Im} f^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned that , right?

Comment: You've written that $R\subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Perhaps you want $R\subset{\mathbb{R}}$? Moreover, the preimage lives in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so there's no need to discuss the imaginary part of it, unless you meant the preimage of the real part of $f$ and the imaginary part of $f$ as distinct functions. But even then the former issue remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $I_1,I_2$ are subsets of $\mathbb R$ then $R=I_1\times I_2$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ and not of $\mathbb C$, wich is the codomain of $f$. Consequently $R$ has no preimage under $f$.

---

Denoting $f(v)=p(v)+iq(v)$ where $p,q:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}$
the following statements are equivalent:

- $v\in f^{-1}(\{x+yi\mid x\in I_{1},y\in I_{2}\})$
- $p(v)\in I_{1}\wedge q(v)\in I_{2}$
- $v\in p^{-1}(I_{1})\wedge v\in q^{-1}(I_{2})$
- $v\in p^{-1}(I_{1})\cap q^{-1}(I_{2})$

So $f^{-1}(\{x+yi\mid x\in I_{1},y\in I_{2}\})=p^{-1}(I_{1})\cap q^{-1}(I_{2})$.

Comment: This one makes sense, thanks